# Attach two view controllers to a single prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

Consider the below scenario

I have a prototype cell, based on the `NSFetchedResultsController` the number of `table view cells` will appear in the `table view controller` say cell A,B,C,D.

Based the on the contents of `tableviewcell` i need to push the segue to different `view controllers`, like when user clicks on the `cells` A,B,C,D to E,F,G,H view controllers respectively.

What is the standard way of designing this scenario?

Comment: any particular reason for the down vote??

Answer (score 1):

As with most complex scenarios, I don't believe that there is one universally accepted standard solution for this. One (I think) clean approach to achieve this kind of behaviour could look like this:

Set up your segues in the Storyboard as `manual` between the destination view controllers and the view controller that acts as your table view's delegate, and give them appropriate identifiers (e.g. "segueE", "segueF", "segueG", "segueH"). Then, in the view controller owning your table view, create a method that encapsulates your mapping between cell content and destination view controller and implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method like so:

```
// Returns "segueE", "segueF", "segueG" or "segueH"
- (NSString *) segueIdentifierForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // your mapping logic
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *segueIdentifier = [self segueIdentifierForIndexPath: indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:self];
}
```

What exactly happens in `segueIdentifierForIndexPath:` depends on the nature of the data you are displaying in the table view, of course.

Comment: thank you for quick reply, i'll implement the above approach and reach you back.